# bottle cap geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a screw generator for 3d printing.
So that it can create a bottle screw and a fitting cap,eventually it should have an option to set a tiny extra gap size between cap and bottle say 0.3mm or so it realy can be screwwed.

I managed to create a simple screw, but i've noticed some screws are indeed like this but others have one two (180 degree appart) three (120 degree appart)  or(90 degree appart)  threads, how to achieve that to below script?
Or should it be approached differently ?.

[image]
The input group is just simple values there's no math inside there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can e.g. use this node setup:

[image]

Here you can control the top size, rotations and no of screws.

[image]

The only "math" in this node tree is the division of tau (2 * pi) divided by the number of screws so i know the rotation z value per screw.

Comment: thats what i was looking for, from here i can go on thanks

Comment: You are welcome